# My copyaddress in JavaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get this to work with my html. I'm doing external js and css into my html. I have all connected into my html file. why doesn't my copyaddress work? not really sure why I'm having this issue...  is it my html or my javascript syntax not correct?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Payment Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="java12.js"></script>
<hr>
<h1>Your Information</h1>
<br>
<form id="myForms">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="firstname">
  <br>
  <br>
  Middle Initial:<br>
  <input type="text"  id="middlename">
  <br>
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname">
  <br>
  <br>
  Address:<br>
  <input type="text"  id="myaddress">
  <br>
  <br>
  City:<br>
  <input type="text"  id="city">
  <br>
  <br>
   State:<br> 
        <select id = "state">
        <option value = "1">Alabama</option>
        <option value = "2">New York</option>
        <option value = "3">Florida</option>
        <option value = "4">California</option>
        </select><br><br>

    Zipcode:<br>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode">
    <br>
    <br>
    Phone: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Phone">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input onclick="copyaddress()" type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
     Billing Address the same as above



<h2>Billing Information</h2>
    Billing Address:<br>
  <input onclick="copy()" type="text" id="myCheck"><br>
  <br>
  <br>
    Billing City:<br>
  <input type="text" name="City">
  <br>
  <br>
    State:<br> 

             <select id="myList">
               <option value = "1">Alabama</option>
               <option value = "2">New York</option>
               <option value = "3">Florida</option>
               <option value = "4">California</option>
             </select><br><br>

    Zipcode:<br>
    <input type="text" id="zip">
    <br>
    <br>
    Phone: <br>
    <input type="text" id="Phone">
    <br>
    <br>
<hr>
<button onclick="OrderSubmitted()">
Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

heres my javascript:

```
function copyaddress() {
    // copy from myaddress to billingaddress
    document.forms["myForms"]["myaddress"].value =
    document.forms["myForms"]["billingaddress"].value;


    alert("checkbox not checked!");
}
function OrderSubmitted() {
    // check if firstname is blank
    var x = document.forms["myForms"]["firstname"].value;
if (x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    // check if lastname is blank
    var x = document.forms["myForms"]["lastname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    // check if middlename is blank
    var x = document.forms["myForms"]["middlename"].value;
if (x == "") {
        alert("Middle name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    // check if myaddress is blank
    var x = document.forms["myForms"]["myaddress"].value;
if (x == "") {
        alert("Address name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    // check if city is blank
    var x = document.forms["myForms"]["city"].value;
if (x == "") {
        alert("City name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    // check if zipcode is blank
    var x = document.forms["myForms"]["zipcode"].value;
if (x == "") {
        alert(" Zipcode must be filled out");
        return false;
    } 
    alert("Order Submitted!") ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have commented out almost all of your code. 
You should uncomment your JavaScript code to result in this:

```js
 function copyadddress() {
        // copy from myaddress to billingaddress
        document.forms["myForms"]["myaddress"].value=
        document.forms["myForms"]["billingaddress"].value;
        alert("checkbox not checked!");
 }

function OrderSubmitted() {
        // check if firstname is blank
        var x = document.forms["myForms"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        // check if lastname is blank
        var x = document.forms["myForms"]["lastname"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("Last name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }

        alert("Order Submitted!");
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem!
PS: In the HTML, make sure you close the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag by adding a >.

Comment: I took the comments out and fixed the > but my copy address still doesn't work